# aws 3: sqs error cURL error 7 on PHP

Tags: php, amazon-sqs

I am getting this error on SQS receiveMessage

```
Exception 'Aws\Sqs\Exception\SqsException' with message '
Error executing "ReceiveMessage" on ; 
AWS HTTP error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to sqs port 443
: Timed out (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)'
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: You ever figure out why this was happening? I'm seeing this every so often with no logical reason why.